# Create a class via a navbar

Tags: html

When, I click on the `home` page, nothing is displayed. ie that the button `home`doesn't react.

[image]

I think my problem is in my HTML code? My syntax is not correct ?

```
 <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a class="active"><href="index.html">Home</a></li>
 </nav>
```

Comment: `<a class="active"><href="index.html">Home</a>` is incorrect, it would be `<a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>`

Comment: @Anurag Srivastava: thank you  Anurag Srivastava it's ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some syntax errors:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```